# Camel and Google App Engine without Spring?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, servlets, apache-camel

So I'm brushing up on the `Camel-GAE` component, and all the tutorials/code samples I've found seem to indicate that you **must** use the Spring DSL (XML) in order to get Camel running on GAE.

This is because `Camel-GAE` depends on `Camel-Servlet`, and the only code samples I've found for configuring a `CamelServlet` in `web.xml` involve:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>appctx.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm really not a huge fan of Spring, and would prefer to do all my DI with something like GIN or Guice. **Is there any way to create a Camel Servlet and define its `CamelContext` without using Spring?** Thanks in advance.

**Update** - error you get when you use JNDI registry on GAE:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.createContext(JndiRegistry.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.getContext(JndiRegistry.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.lookup(JndiRegistry.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.lookup(JndiRegistry.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookup(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1557)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
    at com.ourapp.server.servlets.CamelServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web.xml file does not require to use Spring. So there is no dependency requirement from there. I just think when camel-gae was created, the examples and tutorials was web applications, and for that it was easier to bootstrap Camel using a spring context listener. This is no longer needed: http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-no-spring-example.html

I think we should look into this, and I logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6030

I noticed its spring dependency while I was upgrading camel-gae to use a newer GAE version.

Comment: Thanks @Claus Ibsen (+1) - however it looks like the `ServletListener Component` (which is needed by `Camel Servlet` to allow a Spring-less config) uses the JNDI Registry for bean lookups. If this isn't configurable (i.e. I can change it to use `SimpleRegistry`) then it can't be used on GAE because JNDI access is restricted on GAE. Is the SevletListener's bean registry something that is configurable?

Comment: Also, `ServletListener` only seems to be available for 2.11, which according to Camel's website, hasn't been released yet (!) I was only able to find it by searching explicitly for "Camel 2.11 download". That brought me to [the Apache Download Mirrors page](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/camel/apache-camel/2.11.0/apache-camel-2.11.0.tar.gz) but every link is 404.

Comment: What error do you see from GAE when Jndi is in use? I wonder if we can detect this error and let Camel fallback to SimpleRegistry. A stacktrace of the error helps pin-point to a location where we can add such an improvement

Comment: Thanks. I have logged a ticket to let Camel fallback and use simple when JNDI doesnt work - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6031

Comment: Thanks @Claus Ibsen, I do appreciate you taking the time to log these 2 tickets. But getting back to my original problem, it looks like, for the time being, that I'm stuck with using a Spring config/dependency in my Camel-GAE project, yes? If the only way to specify a non-Spring dependency is through the ServletListener component, and the ServletListener component uses JNDI (which I can't use), then I have no other option than to use Spring for defining my CamelContext, right? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes camel-gae requires Spring at runtime. Only from Camel 2.11 onwards we have improved this and Spring is no longer required. Camel 2.11 has not been released yet, be is expected to be in Feb/Mar this year.